# Python find and return of list

Tags: python, list

I have a list with +/- 2,000 entries.

```
List = [('911', 'Line10', 'Pol87'),
        ('4568', 'Line289', 'Pol022'),
        ('4522', 'Line83', 'Pol45')]
```

required to obtain the desired value of said first cell
by

```
>>>line = search_line(911)
Line10

>>>Pol = search_Pol(4522)
Pol45
```

Multiple calls can be processed quickly and without function?

Comment: General rule: If you're stuck figuring out how to **proceed**, come ask at StackOverflow. If you're stuck figuring out how to **start**, you are in the wrong place. This is not a question -- it's a poorly thought out specification/list of requirements followed by a demand that it be implemented brilliantly. If I want that, I'll talk to my old boss.

Answer (score 1):

A Simple list comprehension would be enough to get all values:

```
>>> List = [('911', 'Line10', 'Pol87'),
...         ('4568', 'Line289', 'Pol022'),
...         ('4522', 'Line83', 'Pol45')]
>>> [t[1] for t in List if t[0]=='911']
['Line10']
>>> [t[2] for t in List if t[0]=='4522']
['Pol45']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way:

```
>>> lst = [('911', 'Line10', 'Pol87'), ('4568', 'Line289', 'Pol022'),   ('4522', 'Line83', 'Pol45')]
>>> filter(lambda x: x[0] == '911', lst)[0][1]
'Line10'
```

Or:

```
def search_line(lst, key):
    for item in lst:
        if item[0] == key:
            return item[1]

print search_line(lst, '911')
```

**Output:**

```
Line10
```

Comment: Filters are pretty inefficient when you pair them with a lambda. I don't know if 2000 is enough entries to really feel the burn on this, but it's something to be aware of.